# Is there a way to change Google Maps background on Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

On the image below you can see that grey background. That is what I would like to change. I am aware you can style your maps [with this handy thing](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/). But there is no option to change the background. I use an empty map, with my custom overlay image only, so I have only the background color and my ground overlay object.

```
mMap = googleMap;
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

customMapOverlay = new 
GroundOverlayOptions()
.image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.test_image)
.position(.....);

mapOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(customMapOverlay);
```

And it would be not a very elegant solution to [style](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling) all map elements the same, so it looks like a solid background color. I could do that at the end. But it worth a question to know if there is an official way to do this?

[image]

Comment: The JS API has a `backgroundColor` property in the map options. Is there no such thing in the Android SDK? If there is no such option you can open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188870).

Comment: The javascript one I found too.I did not find anything like that. There seems to be one way to style the map and it is missing that.

Answer (score -3):

You can try this :

```
 mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

or

```
 mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

or

```
 mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
```

or

```
 mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
```

Comment: That is not solution to my question. All of these still put the same gray background around the map. What I have now is an empty map with a custom image overlay. As I only need the controls of the maps engine, not the data from it.